# How to share Angular service from the library generated by ng generate library?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

I am trying to share a service from the npm package which I generated using `ng g library` with the hosting angular application. I know how to do it for components or directives, but when it comes to services I am lost.

In the library I have the following files:

- authentication.service.ts
- authentication.module.ts

All are mentioned in the `public-api.ts` and I am able to import them in my hosting app.

**authentication.service.ts:** (I also tried it without `providedIn: 'root'`)

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {
...
}
```

**authentication.module.ts:**

```js
@NgModule({
})
export class AuthenticationModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: AuthenticationModule,
      providers: [AuthenticationService]
    };
  }
}
```

**hosting app's app.module.ts:**

```js
import { AuthenticationService } from '@custom/lib';
import { AuthenticationModule } from '@custom/lib';

export function appInitFactory(
    injector: Injector,
    authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
    configService: ConfigService
  ): any {
    return () =>
      loadConfig(configService, authenticationService)
        .then(() => checkLogIn(injector, authenticationService));
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AuthenticationModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthenticationService,
    {
      provide: LocationStrategy,
      useClass: HashLocationStrategy
    },
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: appInitFactory,
      deps: [Injector, AuthenticationService, ConfigService],
      multi: true,
    }

  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I want to inject the `AuthenticationService` into the `appInitFactory` because there I am loading an app configuration from JSON file and checking the authentication before the hosting app is initialized.

The error I am getting is:

```
core.js:15723 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AuthenticationService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AuthenticationService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for AuthenticationService!
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AuthenticationService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AuthenticationService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for AuthenticationService!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get
```

Does anyone have an idea what might be causing this error?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

isn't needed. Simply use

```
@Injectable()
```

as you're already providing it in the `forRoot` method.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. But it is not working.

```
Uncaught Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[InjectionToken Application Initializer -> AuthenticationService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[InjectionToken Application Initializer -> AuthenticationService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for AuthenticationService!
```

I think there is still a problem with:
```typescript
{
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: appInitFactory,
      deps: [Injector, AuthenticationService, ConfigService],
      multi: true,
}
```
Any other thoughts?

Comment: @michal-husak let me think

Comment: @michal-husak how's your public-api file?

Comment: @michal-husak btw, re-place the AuthenticationService in the AppModule providers, and re-try with only @Injectable()

Comment: I removed `--aot` from my `ng serve` and it is throwing a tottaly different error, caused by something different - easily resolvable.

Comment: @michal-husak oh ok! Let me know what's the error, I'm curious

Comment: I was wrong, it is again throwing `NullInjectorError: No provider for AuthenticationService!`
I have to try out some other things :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198329/discussion-between-lppedd-and-michal-husak).